# Different user asked same type of questions two times

Tags: discussion, questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133120/using-hyperlinks-in-textview

and

[Using an hyperlink in textview as a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131897/using-an-hyperlink-in-textview-as-a-word)

asked by the different user. I can't make it duplicate because there is no accept answer found to any question.

Comment: *I accidently posted that on my new account ...* – must be heading for a Ban.

Comment: That means that user has two accounts. one for question and another for answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In future, please flag one of the questions for "in need of moderator attention", and bring it to our attention that way.

FWIW, a question doesn't need an accepted answer in order for you to mark it as a duplicate; it needs an *upvoted* answer.

Comment: yes right actually i was confused what to do that's why asked here.

Comment: Nice. I was wondering how that user got nuked so quickly. This is good to know. I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to flag this kind of thing for a moderator, since it didn't seem that the accounts were upvoting each other.

Comment: @MikeM.: It's extremely hard for normal users to see voting correlations between users, and to detect other behaviour which goes against the site rules (e.g. creating other accounts to bypass suspensions/ post bans). It is therefore perfectly OK for you guys to raise your suspicions via flags in these circumstances.